# how to add and remove processing-instruction in xml with xquery

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, xquery

I want to add and remove a processing-instruction as same as

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="OtxViewer.xsl" ?>
```

into a xml file with xquery but i cannot. 
please help me for a solution?

Comment: what you cannot find?

Answer (score 4):

To remove the processing instruction you can copy all top-level nodes apart from the processing instruction, for example:

```
document {
    doc("file:/c:/Untitled1.xml")/node()[not(. instance of processing-instruction(xml-stylesheet))]
}
```

to add a processing instruction you can insert it in a new document and copy in the top-level nodes from the old document, for example:

```
document {
    processing-instruction xml-stylesheet {
        'type="text/xsl" href="OtxViewer.xsl"'
    },
    doc("file:/c:/Untitled1.xml")/node()
}
```